# Restsharp vs Postman - content-type for a video

Tags: postman, restsharp

For testing one of our API endpoints, I need to upload a video. Our testing framework uses RestSharp.

The call works with Postman, which generates the following relevant headers and body:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------285414664033564173408812
Accept: */* 
content-length: 1055942

----------------------------285414664033564173408812
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="uservideo.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4  
// binary data here
```

Now, when attempting the same using RestSharp, the request is constructed as follows but it fails:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------28947758029299
Content-Length: 1055956

-------------------------------28947758029299
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uservideoTest"; filename="uservideo.mp4"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
// binary data here
```

The code used is as follows:

```
restRequest.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
restRequest.AddFile(request.FileName, request.FullPath);
```

Is it possible to have the RestSharp request constructed like the Postman request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, the answer is:

```
restRequest.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
restRequest.AddFile(request.FileName, request.FullPath, "video/mp4");
```